# base case to returning false on a condition prolog

Tags: prolog

I am working on a basic project in Prolog. I want to write a function that returns a number based on the input list. I also want to make sure that when the input list is empty, the result is false. 
The function should be like this 
parseList(List, N) where N is a number. I would like to know a way that returns False when we try

```
parseList([], N).
```

where N is any number.

I tried doing this for the base case

```
parseList([], False).
```

However,this does not seem to work.

Could anyone please help me with this? Thank You!

Comment: You don't "return" a value of `false` in Prolog. A predicate fails (results in `false`) if it cannot succeed with the given arguments. So the absence of a predicate clause that supports the empty list will automatically fail. Just leave `parseList([], N)` out of your code.

Comment: But, shouldn't there be a base case to support the predicate, .i.e. a stopping point for the predicate when the list is not empty?

Comment: Your base case doesn't have to handle an empty list. It could handle a list of one element, *e.g.*, `parseList([X], N) :- ...` then your recursive case could handle 2 or more elements, `parseList([X,Y|T], N) :- ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lurker said in his comment, in this instance, leaving out the empty list condition and handling the list of one element will cause the empty list to fail. However, in the more general case, if you want to declare a rule that fails, simply include `false`, because that can never be true, or `fail` which does the same. For example:

```
parseList([],_) :- false.
```

or (now deprecated)

```
parseList([],_) :- fail.
```

(where `_` is used to denote an unimportant variable, otherwise a singleton-variable-warning will be triggered).

Comment: `false/0` is the better choice and more recent addition to the ISO standard: It is the more obvious opposite of `true/0`. `fail/0` is the opposite of `succeed/0`, which isn't available at all.